# Цикл php с проверкой значений и последующей обработкой условий

Tags: php, foreach

Всем привет.
В проект необходимо написать проверку на наличие действующего логина, столкнулся с проблемой, а именно не понимаю как ее реализовать.
Мой текущий код:

```
function SearchFreeLogin($login)
{
    foreach ($login as $checklogin)
    {
        $search = SearchLogin($checklogin);
        if {

        }
        else {

        }
    }
}
```

Не понимаю, как быть дальше.
Через функцию SearchLogin я проверяю есть ли совпадения (возвращается массив).
Логин генерируется с помощью транслитерации, из-за чего может быть совпадение логина (чего я пытаюсь избежать в этой функции).
Я хочу через цикл искать наличие совпадения, и если оно есть - дописывать к логину цифру 1, если логин с цифрой 1 занят, то дописывать 2 и т.д.
К примеру:

1. Сегодня регистрируется логин Ivanov.
2. Через день кто-то еще пробует создать логин Ivanov, но т.к. он занят, будет автоматически создан логин Ivanov1

Comment: что возвращает SearchLogin ?

Answer (score 1):

```
function SearchFreeLogin($login)
{
   $i = 0;
   // Если результат SearchLogin приводится к логическому значению
   // Если нет, то измените условие
   while(SearchLogin($login . ($i ? $i : '')) {
      $i++;
   }
   return($login . ($i ? $i : ''));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В код добавлены комментарии

```
$i = 1;
// сохраняем изначальный логин
$tempLogin = $checklogin;
while (true) {
    $search = SearchLogin($checklogin);
    // проверяем есть ли совпадение
    if ($search) {
        // меняем логин и проверяем заново
        $checklogin = $tempLogin . $i++;
    } else {
       //регистрируем нового пользователя и прерываем цикл
       break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Может я дурак... Но в итоге дописывает только 1 раз цифру, хотя в БД искусственно создал логины с цифрой 2 и 3. Я фактически взял ваш код, поменял $checklogin на $login и обернул все в функцию.

Comment: отлаживайте код и смотрите на какой строчке приходит некорректное значение. Сейчас сказать что-то определённое нельзя. Возможно, ваша функция `SearchLogin` работает неправильно